# Блокировку по IP-адресу всегда можно обойти при помощи его подделки (IP address spoofing)?

Tags: ip

Я ничего не понимаю в IP, единственное что я прочитал это небольшую статью: What is IP Spoofing? https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/ddos/glossary/ip-spoofing/

Comment: Обычно если ничего не понимают, то читают что-нибудь побольше, чем небольшая статья.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, блокировки по IP всегда можно обойти при помощи подделки IP.

Представь себе ночной клуб, в котором посетителей блокируют по городу рождения - тех, кто родился в Караганде туда не пускают. И вот туда приходит Толян из Караганды, ему охранник на входе: Молодой человек, вы в каком городе родились? Толян из Караганды отвечает: В Тынде. Охранник ему: хорошо, проходите. Вот таким образом Толян применил технологию city spoofing и прошел через фаервол в ночной клуб.

Comment: В итоге блокировки по IP-адресу в файрволе работают так же как кодовый замок? То есть просто неизвестно какой именно IP-адрес надо подделывать.

Comment: Блокировки по IP работают по принципу: если пришло из адреса в черном списке - не пущать. А по приниципу кодового замка работает авторизация через пароль, например.

Comment: Я имел ввиду если есть один единственный разрешённый IP-адрес, а все остальные заблокированы. Такие блокировки очень часто используются в самых разных приложениях.